# Modal dinamico y en cada uno de ellos un mapa con Geocoder

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tardes estoy iterando unos registros de mi base de datos y en cada uno de ellos itero también un modal para poder ver el resto de la información del registro. Hasta ahí voy bien, el problema es que quiero cargar por cada modal un mapa cogiendo la dirección del registro y hasta ahora solo consigo que me coja del primer registro.

```
@foreach ($locales as $item)
   ......
   ......
<a href="#verMensajes{{ $item->id }}" data-user="{{ $item->id }}" data-toggle="modal" class="mydrop2a abrModal" style="color: #7460ee;" data-target="#verMensajes{{ $item->id }}" id="{{ $item->id }}"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a>
   ......
<div class="modal left fade modalLat" id="verMensajes{{ $item->id }}" tabindex="" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="verMensajesLabel{{ $item->id }}" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";>
    <div class="modal-dialog myModal" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content"> 
            <ul>  
               <li>
                 <input type="hidden" value="{{ $item->direccion }} {{ $item->municipio }} {{ $item->provincia }}" id="address">
                 <h5>Ubicación</h5>
                 <div id="mapaPropiedad"></div>
                </li>
             </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
 @endforeach
```

**Luego el JavaScript**

```
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    function initMap() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.4078968, -0.4317228);
        var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 18,
        center: latlng,
        mapId: '6d7bc70ff139bf71',
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapaPropiedad'), mapOptions);
        codeAddress()
    }

    function codeAddress() {
        
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
        console.log(address);
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
        });
    }
```

He intentado cambiar los `document.getElementById('mapaPropiedad')` por `document.getElementsByClassName` también metiendo el javascript dentro del foreach pero nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es debido a que en cada iteración que haces, creas un elemento de tipo `<input type="hidden" value="{{ $item->direccion }} {{ $item->municipio }} {{ $item->provincia }}" id="address">`  donde se establece un id. El id, tiene que ser único dentro del DOM y al intentar recuperar ese elemento, aunque haya varios con el mismo Id, sólo va a recoger el primero que encuentre. Mi recomendación es, que le establezcas un id o una clase única en cada iteración, tal y como haces `<div class="modal left fade modalLat" id="verMensajes{{ $item->id }}`. Como ejemplo, podrías establecer en cada uno de los input su id, como : `<input type="hidden" value="{{ $item->direccion }} {{ $item->municipio }} {{ $item->provincia }}" id="address_{{ $item->id }}">`